# How to create directory and change it's owner with the deb package

Tags: permissions, package-management, directory, deb, chown

I need to create deb package that will create directory for logs. I want to create directory `/var/logs/my_package` and to change it's owner to `my_user`.

In [the docs there is information](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/dother.en.html#dirs) that I can create file `debian/dir`. But there is info that this is not the best way to do it. And there is no info how one should change there directory owner (I'm thinking about placing command `chown my_user.my_user /var/logs/my_package`it in `debian/postinst` file).

What is the recommended way to create directory with the deb package?

Answer (score 11):

You were right, you need a `debian/my_package.postinst` file to perform such operation:

```
#!/bin/sh

#DEBHELPER#

set -e

DIR="/var/log/my_package/"
USER="my_user"

mkdir -p ${DIR}    
if id -u ${USER} > /dev/null 2>&1; then    
    chown ${USER}:${USER} ${DIR}
fi
```

**Note**: The script checks if the user exists before calling `chown`.

Comment: I'm extremely sorry, but this does not answer my question.

Comment: Please explain why this postinst script does not answer your original question. I'm a bit puzzled now.

Comment: I'm sorry that I haven't explain it in the proper manner. Your solution works fine and this is what I have implemented. But the [docs](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/dother.en.html#dirs) say `This generally means there is a problem with the Makefile.` I understand this message that there is some other way to do it. And I want to find out what is the recomened way to do this task.

Comment: The directory creation could be done in `debian/rules` which is the `Makefile` for debian packages. Since I didn't know your `debian/rules` I preferred to propose a solution based on a single file. But the `chown` command must be a post-installation process. debian/dirs should be avoided but my initial answer is perfectly fine. Please vote and accept it, thanks.

Comment: There is a typo. The ending should be `postinst` and not `postint`.

Answer (score 6):

You do not need to create a `postinst` script, but the solution is still a bit tricky. I use `dh` wildcard in `debian/rules`:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f
%:
        dh $@

binary:
        dh $@
```

which does all the needed stuff. But I need to override some dir's ownership (lets call it data). So I must make some exception, I use special directives as follow:

```
    override_dh_install:
        dh_install   #calls default *.install and *.dirs installation
        install -d -o www-data -g www-data $(CURDIR)/debian/<package_name>/var/www/<something>/data
```

The data directory do not need to be in `*.dirs` file. But still there is one trick. Debhelper contains script dh_fixperms, which would fix ownership back to root, so we need to override too:

```
override_dh_fixperms:
    dh_fixperms --exclude data
```

That's all. Keep in mind the data dir does not count as a `conffile`, so it will be removed on package removal. If you need to make it a `conffile`, it is another story.

Comment: Does this require that the user and group exists on the system where the package is built? And if yes, is there a way to ensure that with a Debian-based mechanism?

Comment: This will create the directories on the system used to build the debian package,  _not_ the system the package is installed on.

Comment: @moritz Yes. That is the drawback of this technique. It needs to exist on both systems.

Comment: I don't think that it makes sense to have a `*.dirs` and then use `install -d ...` since both create the directories. On my end, I simply use `chown ...` in the `rules` file.

Answer (score 0):

I've read that if you have to use the `debian/[<package>.]dirs` file, that means your `make install` step did not do its job properly. That step should create that folder.

Here are the issues I can see with this:

1. `make install` can't install anything under a directory other than `/usr` (for a Debian package), so it's useless if you want a directory under `/etc/...`, `/var/lib/<package>/...`, etc.
2. If you use `mkdir -p ...` in your `debian/[<package>.]postinst` script, then you need to manually remove it with an `rmdir ...` in your `debian/[<package>.].postrm` script.

So the solution proposed by Marek Šimon is the same as mine, the only difference is that I use `chown ...` instead of `install -d ...` although with the `install -d ...` you can avoid the `debian/[<package>.]dirs` altogether. Personally, I like to see a list of the directories I create in a separate file. It looks much clearer.

#### Example

Create the directories:

```
# in debian/package.dirs
/etc/package/magic/configuration
/var/www/package/data
```

Change the ownership:

```
# in debian/rules
override_dh_fixperms:
    dh_fixperms
    chmod 700 debian/tmp/var/www/package/data
    chown www-data:www-data debian/tmp/var/www/package/data
```

**WARNING:** The `debian/rules` file uses tabs to indent the code under a target name. This is important.

As shown in the example, I also often change the permissions (`chmod`).

The `debian/tmp/...` introducer is required if you create two or more packages. I'm not too sure what it is if you are creating a single package (in  part because it's really rare for my projects to have a single package and also many paths change when you add a second package so instead I always include at least a `package-doc.install` even if mostly empty so that way it won't change on me).

#### Final Note

If you are creating a public Debian package which is to be accepted by Debian or Ubuntu, you probably want to follow Sylvain Pineau's solution. Keep in mind that on a purge you need to remove your directory (unless the user created its own files in it).