# Create an installer/package for a script

Tags: bash, package-management, scripts, deb

Please keep in mind this is the first time I've ever written a bash script, worked on Linux just the first time really that I'm trying to achieve something like this.

I've written a script that I now want to make available to other people, I will be posting it on Github and what not. I've read and followed [this](http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/index.html) up until step 6. But I can't seem to figure out how to apply it for my own needs.

What I have is three scripts. One script makes use of the two others. They are right now just sitting in a directory. What I want to do is make it installable by making a `.deb` package of it.

When you install the package I want the scripts to be placed in a corresponding directory in `/etc` and I want to be able to create the `man page` and alias etc in the install process so everything will work after installing the program.

Could someone help me out on how to do this, or point me to a good tutorial that will help me to figure this out.

Comment: Follow the linked duplicate. That's what I personally use for all my scripts.

Comment: This is for bash but looking at it it looks like a lot of stuff is the same for python as for bash. Since I already created files like control

Comment: Python or bash, the idea is the same -  you will need to tell the `install` where to throw each of your scripts.

Comment: I'm going throug it right now I'll let you know if i'm able to do what I'm aiming for

Comment: @Serg can you tell the install file to create directories as well?
For instance I want to place some stuff in /etc/myscriptname/
would I just add this location in the install script or would I need to add mkdir /etc/myscriptname/ first?

Comment: I think you can add this location to the install script ( I don't use it , so not 100% sure), although there's other ways,too: http://askubuntu.com/q/439780/295286

Comment: @Serg
great thank you that's exactly what I needed

Comment: @Serg one last question. I have successfully created the .deb package now. However I was wondering how would I make sure people can install it by just running  `apt-get install <mypackage>` ?

Comment: you will need to create a Personal Package Archive(PPA) on launchpad for that (https://launchpad.net/).  Once you have that, people can add your PPA to their list, run `apt-get update` and then `apt-get install`. There's also other ways, but if you want `apt-get` way, you need to have PPA created

Comment: @Serg alread have a PPA will look into it more thanks!

Comment: @Serg I have another question. I wanted to fix a bug (still set to UNRELEASED) but when I regenerate the package and install it again it doesn't install it correctly. Is there something special I need to do before generating/installing it again?

Comment: Well, I would recommend you ask another question on the site, and provide the exact error you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

[Github - fpm - Effing Package Management](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm/wiki)
I think this is what you need.
For another tool for easy packaging:
[Debreate](https://antumdeluge.github.io/debreate-web)
For a guide involving a few tools:
[create a .deb Package from scripts or binaries](https://askubuntu.com/a/27731/636480)
All the answers here are relevant for both Python and Bash:
[How do I create a deb package for a single python script?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90764/how-do-i-create-a-deb-package-for-a-single-python-script)
Especially the first answer in the above link is very useful.
If you wish to learn all of it without missing anything consider this:
[Ubuntu Packaging](http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/)

Comment: I was aware of the `fpm` project indeed. However I need to do things on install and I don't see any documentation on how to achieve this with `fpm`

Comment: I don't think it's supported. Maybe you really need to start from the basics. I could also suggest that you try snapcraft. But I guess that might not help in your case.

Comment: BTW, is this bash or python?

Comment: this is for bash

Comment: Should still be the same. The answers remain relevant, at least most of them.

Comment: is this conclusive enough?