# In debian packaging (dpkg) installer, postinst disappears

Tags: permissions, dpkg

I need to modify a `dpkg` installer, since one file does not run correctly after being installed, and it needs to be owned by root but run with caller user id.

I tried to put the commands required in a `postinst` file, but nothing happens.

```
#!/bin/sh

chown root /data/usr/bin/TheApp
chgrp root /data/usr/bin/TheApp
chmod +s /data/usr/bin/TheApp

exit 0
```

Where should I place the commands such that they are performed during `dpkg -i` ?
[I have seen similar questions, most say to put in `postinst`](https://askubuntu.com/a/439867/321741) - if that is correct, something must be wrong with the postinst file.

I noticed that the `postinst` file exists in the folder created - but not in the compressed `.deb` file.

What can be keeping the postinst file from being copied over to the debian package when calling `dpkg -b` ?

Comment: @K7AAY Removed reference to debian installer. It is pure ubuntu.

Comment: @Melebius: I am trying to modify the options when creating a package. It is common when writing software. Has nothing to do with using published packages.

Answer (score 0):

The postinst file was correct - but it did not get copied in the installer.

Reasons -

Seems all 4 files are needed (postinst, postrm, preinst, prerm) - and their permission must be set `(must be >=0555 and <=0775)`
`